# Iterating an HTMLCollection object using for-of loop

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6, htmlcollection, babel-polyfill

I'm using [babel-polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/) and I'm trying to iterate an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) object using for-of loop:

```
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('some-class')
for (const element of elements) {
  console.log(element)
}
```

It's not working. I'm getting an error `elements[Symbol.iterator] is not a function`. How to make it work correctly?

Comment: To explain a few things that you misunderstood: core-js is a part of babel-polyfill, so there's no point in including it twice. If typing `Symbol.iterator` into console works, it only means that this symbol exists; it doesn't necessarily mean that `elements` have a `Symbol.iterator` property. for-of loop doesn't treat anything as an array—it simply invokes the `@@iterator` method of an object.

Comment: Also, in case you don't know what is an HTMLCollection object: it's an object returned by `document.getElementsByClassName()`.

Comment: @Gothdo, to clarify, I was not ever including both core-js and babel-polyfill: I had just tried importing them at different times in order to see if one or the other would work. Nonetheless, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @thesublimeobject Having `Symbol.iterator` doesn't mean that `elements[Symbol.iterator]` should be there.
Wether `elements` expose an _iterator_ interface (so `[Symbol.iterator]` method) is related to its type. It simply looks as in your case this type doesn't expose it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From ["Iterable DOM collections" on the core-js GitHub page](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#iterable-dom-collections):

> Some DOM collections should have [iterable
>   interface](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#idl-iterable) or should be
>   [inherited from
>   `Array`](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#LegacyArrayClass). That mean
>   they should have `keys`, `values`, `entries` and `@@iterator` methods
>   for iteration. So add them. Module
>   [`web.dom.iterable`](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/v2.4.1/modules/web.dom.iterable.js):
>
> ```
> {
>   NodeList,
>   DOMTokenList,
>   MediaList,
>   StyleSheetList,
>   CSSRuleList
> }
>   #values()     -> iterator
>   #keys()       -> iterator
>   #entries()    -> iterator
>   #@@iterator() -> iterator (values)
> ```

As you can see, that list doesn't include `HTMLCollection`. In order to be able to use for-of loop with `HTMLCollection`, you have to manually assign `Array.prototype.values` to `HTMLCollection.prototype[Symbol.iterator]`. See this example:

```js
HTMLCollection.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = Array.prototype.values

for (const element of document.getElementsByTagName('a')) {
  console.log(element.href)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/2.4.1/core.min.js"></script>
<a href="//www.google.com">Google</a>
<a href="//www.github.com">GitHub</a>
```

Alternatively, you can just use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), which a returns a `NodeList` object.

Comment: @zer00ne Added to answer.

Comment: @Gothdo This is an extremely useful answer. Thank you very much. I misunderstood the iterable spec and now understand exactly why I was having this issue.